# PHP: Sending mails with attachment to email accounts from database

Tags: php, database, email, attachment

I have been trying to get an email form that will send emails with attachments to email adresses which are stored in a database. I already have a script that will send an email to the email adresses in my database and I have a script that sends 1 attachment to 1 email and both of them work fine. The problem however is that I can't get them combined into 1 script. I have tried to combine the 2 into 1 many times but I can seem to figure it out. Since I'm still a student I am still learning how to do these things.

I will post the code I have below to show you what I have so far. If anyone has any tips or could show me how to do it it would be very helpful.

config.php

```
<?php
$server="localhost";
$database="NAW";
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="something";
$fromadmin="test@test.com";
$table="Email";
$table_email="Email";
?>
```

Send mails to email adresses in database:

```
<?php
include "header.php"; 
include "config.php"; 

if( $_POST || $_FILES )
{
$seconds=$_POST['seconds'];
$subject=$_POST['subj'];
$messagesend=$_POST['message'];
    mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass)
  or die ("Database CONNECT Error"); 
    $resultquery = mysql_db_query($database, "select * from $table");

while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($resultquery)) 
{ 
    $emailinfo=$myemail;    
    $mailto=$query[$table_email];
    mail($mailto, $subject, $messagesend , "From:".$fromadmin."\nReply-To:".$fromadmin."\n"); 
    echo 'Mail sent to '.$mailto.'<br>';
    sleep($seconds);
}
echo 'Mails sent. Go <a href="massmail.php">Back</a>';
}
  else 
{
?>
<table height="250" cellpadding="1">
<tr><td valign="top">
<h2>Mail Sender</h2><br><form action="massmail.php" method="POST">

          <div align="center"> 
          <table cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
          <tr>
          <td>
          Subject:
          </td>
          <td>
          <input type="text" align="left" name="subj" size="66">
          </td>


          </tr>
          <tr><td align="left" valign="top">
            Message Text:</td><td align="left"> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="60"                ></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="left">
            Seconds between messages:<input type="text" size="10" name="seconds" value="0.1"> (seconds)
                </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">    
            <input type="submit" value="Send mass mails" name="submit" >
            </Td>
            </tr>

            </table>
          </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
}
include "footer.php";    
?>
```

Send a mail with an attachment:

```
<?php
if( $_POST || $_FILES )
{
        // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
        // Here 
        $from = "test@test.com";
        $to = "test2@test.com";
        $subject = "Mail with Attachment";
        $message = "This is the message body and to it I will append the attachments.";
        $headers = "From: $from";

        // boundary
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        // headers for attachment
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

        // multipart boundary
        $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
        fixFilesArray($_FILES['attachment']);
        foreach ($_FILES['attachment'] as $position => $file) 
        {
                // should output array with indices name, type, tmp_name, error, size
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                $fp     = @fopen($file['tmp_name'],"rb");
                $data   = @fread($fp,filesize($file['tmp_name']));
                @fclose($fp);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$file['name']."\"\n"."Content-Description: ".$file['name']."\n" ."Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$file['name']."\";size=".$file['size'].";\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        }
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
        $returnpath = "-f" . $from;
        $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
        if($ok){ return 1; } else { return 0; }
}
//This function will correct file array from $_FILES[[file][position]] to $_FILES[[position][file]] .. Very important

function fixFilesArray(&$files)
{
        $names = array( 'name' => 1, 'type' => 1, 'tmp_name' => 1, 'error' => 1, 'size' => 1);

        foreach ($files as $key => $part) {
                // only deal with valid keys and multiple files
                $key = (string) $key;
                if (isset($names[$key]) && is_array($part)) {
                        foreach ($part as $position => $value) {
                                $files[$position][$key] = $value;
                        }
                        // remove old key reference
                        unset($files[$key]);
                }
        }
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="bijlagetest.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="attachment[]"><br/>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do your self a favour use [swiftmailier](http://swiftmailer.org/), or [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to attach Files the User first needs an Upload-Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

to save the File in PHP do something like this

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

So now you have the Files to send as Attachment, rewrite your script to a function that can handle multiple attachments...

something like this should work...

```
<?php

function sendMail($to, $from, $subject, $message, $attachments){

$headers = "From: $from";

// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($attachments);$x++){
    $file = fopen($attachments[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,attachmentsize($attachments[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$attachments[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$attachments[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}

// send

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { 
    echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
} 
}
?>
```

I have not tested this code but it should push you in the right direction ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**
**First create one folder temp.**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
                                    //Database credentials
    $mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_db_user = "root";
    $mysql_db_password = "";
    $mysql_db_database = "reassurance";
    $con = mysql_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_db_database, $con) or die("Could not select database");
    $filename='temp/test.csv';
    //$filename='temp/'.$test.'.csv';
    $fp=fopen($filename,"w");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contactus`");

    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $seperator="";

    $comma="";

    foreach($row as $name =>$value)

    {

    $seperator.=$comma.''.str_replace('','""',$name);
    $comma=",";

    }
    $seperator.="\n";
     $seperator;

    fputs($fp,$seperator);

    mysql_data_seek($sql,0);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

    {

    $seperator="";

    $comma="";
    foreach($row as $name =>$value)

    {

    $seperator.=$comma.''.str_replace('','""',$value);
    $comma=",";

    }

    $seperator.="\n";
    fputs($fp,$seperator);

    }

    fclose($fp);
    $my_file ='test.csv';
    $path = "temp/";


    $from_name = "Hara Prasad Hota";

    $from_mail = "haraprasad@lemonpeak.com";

    $mailto = "haraprasad@lemonpeak.com";

    $subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";

    $message = "Hallo,\r\n do you got attachment? I hope it is working.\r\n\r\Hara";

    $replyto="haraprasad@lemonpeak.com";
    $file = $path.$my_file;
        $file_size = filesize($file);


    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);

    fclose($handle);

    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $name = basename($file);

     $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";

    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

     $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";

    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";

    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here

    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

    $header .= "--".$uid."--";

    mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)
    ?>
```